# SparkR summary() extracting

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I have a question about the *summary()* method in SparkR by using the Random Forest Regression. The model building process works fine, but I'm interesting in the ***featureImportance*** of one of the result of the algorithm. I want to store the ***featureImportance*** variables into a SparkDataFrame to visualize them, but I do not have any idea how to transfer/extract it.

```
model <- spark.randomForest(x1, x2 , x3, type = "regression", maxDepth = 30, maxBins = 50, numTrees=50, impurity="variance", featureSubsetStrategy="all")

summaryRF <- summary(model)

summaryRF$feature:
1. 'x1'
2. 'x2'
3. 'x3'

summaryRF$featureImportances: 
'(3,[0,1,2],[0.01324152135,0.0545454422,0.0322122334])'
```

Is there any solution to get the *featureImportance* values out of the list object and store it in a SparkDataFrame?

Using the *collect()* method gives the following error code:

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘collect’ for signature ‘"character"’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`summaryRF` is not a `SparkDataFrame` anymore, that's why `collect` doesn't work :)

`summaryRF$featureImportances` is a `character string` (on the `Spark` side it a `SparseVector` which can't currently (v. 2.1.0) be serialised to and from `R`, which i guess is why it gets coerced into a `string`).

so as far as i can tell, you have to extract the relevant bits by manipulating the string directly:

```
# extract the feature indexes and feature importances strings:
fimpList <- strsplit(gsub("\\(.*?\\[","",summaryRF$featureImportances),"\\],\\[")

# split the index and feature importances strings into vectors (and remove "])" from the last record):
fimp <- lapply(fimpList, function(x) strsplit(gsub("\\]\\)","",x),","))

# it's now a list of lists, but you can make this into a dataframe if you like:
fimpDF <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind,(fimp[[1]])))
```

eta: by the way, indexes in `Spark` start at 0, so if you want to merge on the feature index in `summaryRF$featureImportances` when joining the feature names in `summaryRf$features` you have to take that into account:

```
featureNameAndIndex <- data.frame(featureName = unlist(summaryRf$features),
                                  featureIndex = c(0:(length(summaryRf$features)-1))),
                                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```